# How to fix my NetworkPolicy not working problem?

Tags: kubernetes

I am setting up Network Policy in k8s, but it does not work as my expectation.

My k8s has network policy enabled. It has to namespaces:

```
- proxy
- jupyter
```

Under namespace jupyter, it has lots of jupyter pods, and each jupyter pod has a service for it to provide cluster IP.
Under namespace proxy, I have a node-proxy forwarding requests to each jupyter.
The structure is like this:

```
- namespace proxy
   - pod node-proxy
- namespace jupyter
   - service a
   - pod a
   - service b
   - pod b
   - ...
```

I create a network policy like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
  namespace: jupyter
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  - Ingress
  Ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          ns: proxy
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8888
```

I want every jupyter pod can only be accessed by node-proxy. But when I enable above yaml file, node-proxy cannot access jupyter. Anything wrong?

Comment: which platform runs your cluster (aws/gcp etc)?

Comment: It's on aliyun, similar to aws.

Answer (score 1):

A stupid question. I have a typo in it.

```
Ingress:
```

chang to

```
ingress:
```